# Filtering data using external cell as criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a dashboard, where I have to use a custom filter for my data. Its because I have almost 800 data points, and I have to plot all of them. But I am not interested in plotting all of them, instead I want a filter cell. Where I can define the filter criteria.

For example, lets say if I want data only for more than 1, then I should be able to write 1 into that cell, and it should automatically filter the data. Likewise, if I want data between 0.5 and 1, then I could write these numbers into two cells and get the data filtered. Instead of clicking on tables top block and manually writing the numbers into pop-up. I have been trying to find a way to do it, but have been unsuccessful. In the beginning, I kind of tried using IF statement, so that the rows which has the values would come out, but it also did not work.

**UPDATE**

So I have been succesfull in making multiple filters using VBA code in excel. But here is the situation. My data is in Table form and is in Sheet, 'Data'. Then I have another sheet called Dashboard. So I need some help with two points:

1) I make it work for Top 5 and Bottom 5 filters. But I can not make it work for >1 code. I am using the following code (which I found from internet):

```
Sub Filter_Morethan1()

Dim lo As ListObject
Dim iCol As Long

  Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3")

  'Set filter field
  iCol = lo.ListColumns("Cost Prices").Index

  'Apply filters to a column (field)
  lo.Range.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=">1", Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

But when i run the code, it says "Runtime Error 1004: Autofilter method of Range Class failed". The following line in my code turns yellow when i click on debug

```
lo.Range.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=">1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

2) Secondly, I am trying to activate some click buttons in a different sheet. I wish the user should be able to click on those buttons and the data would be filtered. The buttons work when I activate them in the 'same' sheet, but when I make the buttons in the different sheet, then I get an error of '*Run-time error 9: subscript out of range"*.

Is there anyone who can help with these two cases?

**UPDATE2**

The two sheets which I have mentioned are related in a way that, in one sheet, I only insert the Raw Data, which is formatted as a Table. I have almost 890 data rows. The table is defined in Columns A and B. This is the sheet 'Data'. Whereas in 'Dashboard' Sheet, I am plotting the bar graph for all the 900 data points. But the idea is that the 'Macro Buttons' would filter the data in sheet 'Data', hence changing the data being used for Bar Graph in Dashboard Sheet. Its because I am trying to make an interactive dashboard, whereas the user is not allowed to go into the other sheets. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: look into vba change even

Comment: I have tried doing it through VBA as well. I tried defining a variable (string) with the value from the string and then gave the command of >'string', but it does not seem to work there either.

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-subset-of-data-in-a/125e2c19-48db-4b3b-9224-9afdec475228)? Otherwise, please reword to make it clearer what you want.

Comment: While not being 100% sure of exactly what you want, it can more than likely be done with VBA. You said you tried, so paste the code and we can help you with that. Add a small sample with desired outcome so it's easier to visualize what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I have done it using VBA and have almost succeeded in doing so as well now. But have come into a new problem. I have posted my VBA code in my updated question. Hopefully, it can help.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932353/filter-using-array-and-xlfiltervalues)

Comment: @MathCurious314,, I think that unnecessarily you have made the situation complicated,, in updated part you have mentioned 2 sheets but not the use of them also not clear that how they are associated,, if your criteria is variable then instead of value,,  `Criteria1:=">1` better use cell reference and alter it with values to match & filter !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have even tried doing that as well, but the problem is whenever I try to define the cell, it does not work. The way I did was that I defined a String with the Cell Value and then inserted the String into the criteria1, but it didnt give any results either.

But I have updated the question again with more detail.

Comment: @MathCurious314,, it should like `Criteria1:=Range("A1").Value` or if from other sheet `Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value`  and in cell write criteria `>1` without string,,, or better use Advance filter.

Comment: Thank You for your answer.
I found the solution to the problem. I was using ActiveSheet as the reference, and then I simply changed it to Worksheet(#) and now the buttons work from the other sheets as well. I have also solved the other issues.

But Thank You to everyone who took time to comment on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. The issues which I found to be the problem were the following:

- The button was not working in the different sheet because I was using ActiveSheet option, which means that the buttons were only active in the given sheet. Meanwhile the data was inserted into a different sheet. Therefore, I simply changed the code to using

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets(2)
```

This allowed it to work.

- For the other issue where the `>1` was not working, I found the mistake in the `Field:=` option. It is because since I am using a Table, and I wanted to filter out the second column in my table, hence therefore I had to use `Field:=2` instead of `5`.

By doing the above, I was able to solve my problem.

I hope the answer can help others if they ever find themselves in the same problem.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted.